# Does spring @GetMapping work with MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mockmvc

**HelloController.java**

```
@RestController
class HelloController {

@GetMapping(value = "{id}/hello")
public ModelAndView listAPI(@PathVariable("id") String profileId) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    return mav;
 }    
}
```

**HelloControllerTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = HelloConfigTest.class)
class HelloControllerTest {

@Inject
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Inject
private Foo mockFoo

@InjectMocks
HelloController helloController;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Test
public void testHello() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(
        get("/{id}/campaigns", "id1"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk()));
  }  
}

    // I have another test that directly calls the controller method. 
// So I need @InjectMocks to get an instance of the controller

@Test
public void test2() {

    when(mockFoo.getX()).thenReturn(true);
    helloController.saveAPI();
}
```

**HelloConfigTest.java**

```
 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan("com.test.controller")
 class HelloConfigTest {

@Bean
public mockFoo() {
    return Mockito.mock(Foo.class); 
  }
}
```

The response that I get here is 404 and I expect 200.

But it works and I get 200 if I change **@GetMapping** to **@RequestMapping**(value="{id}/hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)

Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: How are you initializing your `MockMvc`?

Comment: Your code (and basic assumptions) works fine for me. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have updated the test class now. I have just not included the Config file

Comment: Please include the minimal version of your config class that reproduces this issue, because with a simple `@EnableWebMvc`, I can't. (The `helloController` field isn't serving any purpose here. Remove it.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have updated the question to show the Config class and explained why I need InjectMocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration is extremely bare bones

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.test.controller")
class HelloConfigTest {
```

It doesn't register any Spring MVC infrastructure beans, either implicitly or explicitly.

When `MockMvc`, internally, creates a `TestDispatcherServlet` to test your `@Controller` class, it has to defer to some default Spring MVC infrastructure types.

Among these infrastructure types is `HandlerMapping` which is

> to be implemented by objects that define a mapping between requests and handler objects.

The default implementation used by the `TestDispatcherSerlet` is `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` (an old class) which looks for `@RequestMapping` *specifically*, it doesn't recursively do a meta-annotation lookup. Your `@GetMapping` annotated method is therefore not found and not registered as a handler.

If, instead, you configure your application context with `@EnableWebMvc`

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.test.controller")
@EnableWebMvc
class HelloConfigTest {
```

Spring will implicitly register a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, which does do this "recursive" lookup for the annotation hierarchy (called *merging*). Since `@GetMapping` is annotated with `@RequestMapping`, the annotated handler method will be found and registered.

---

As for the `@InjectMocks`, note that the instance referenced by the field is different from the one used to handle the request performed by the `MockMvc` object. The former is managed by Mockito, the latter by Spring.

Comment: Bingo! that worked. Thank you!  As for InjectMocks. that test which directly calls the controller method, should be tested using Mockmvc and then I can remove the controller field from the test class

Comment: Your explanation is, seriously, **incredible**.